# Change source code for a R package

Tags: r, package

I'm using a package called NPLR for dose response fitting and plotting. I love the package but on the display it says IC50 when in reality my curves are EC50's. It's literally one character I need to change in the source but I don't know how to access the source code for the package. Is it possible to do this?

-Justin

Comment: Just type in the function name in your console to see the function definition. Then you should be able to copy it and create your new (adjusted) function. Or contact the package maintainer if you think it's a bug.

Comment: you should probably `myEst <- edit(nplr:::.addEstim)` instead since there are some other unexported functions within that function

Comment: Another way to get functions (also internals) from a package is to use      `getAnywhere("function")`